# Copying a 300 Gig file between two ext. hard drives via laptop

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have two external hard drives and a laptop.

I want to copy a single very large file, which is around 300 GB, from one of the external hard drive to the other.

What is a practical way to do that? Any tool that can help?

Desired features, it would be great if:

- the tool/method can recover from
  interruptions (I do not have UPS, and
  blackouts are somewhat likely in the
  area where  I live).
- it were possible to
  suspend and later resume the copy
  process (I may not be able to leave my laptop running for 8-16 hours straight, which is the time I expect the copy process to take in real-life).
- there's a realistic estimate
  of time remaining while copying.

Comment: Laptop operating system?

Comment: Laptop operating system: Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of the question, but I was wondering exactly how long it would take: USB 2.0 has a transfer rate of 480 MBit/s, or 53.248 MB/s. 300 Gigabytes is 307200 Megabytes / 53.248 MB = 5769 seconds = 96 minutes

This free software reviews great and seems to fit your need:

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

Here is one more that also might:

http://www.copyhandler.com/en

Comment: Usb to usb is slower than host hard drive to usb or the other way around, I average 1gb per minute (not exact) on a large set of files when going usb>hard disk, or hard disk>usb, larger files transfer faster than thousands of smaller files, how may directories makes a difference also.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning teracopy, looks good. But regarding "300 Gigabytes is 3072000 Megabytes": I think 300 GByte is more like 307200 Megabyte!!! Not 3072000 Megabyte.

Comment: @gojira Yes, that was a typo...really. :)

Answer (score 2):

[richcopy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/33971726-eeb7-4452-bebf-02ed6518743e/), by one of microsoft's local offices does pretty much everything you mention on the list. And yes, the file is called Hoffmansutilityspotlight.

to steal the feature list on that link

```
1. More powerful, faster and stable than than any other file copying tool.
2. Create several profiles to assign special settings with a specific profile.
3. Copy files from multiple and different locations and save in a single destination.
4. Filter the files based on the date, time and choose to either copy or opt those files.
5. Being on GUI, supports command lines.
6. Suspend and resume file copy at any time.
```